# Very basic JSON question

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON data:

```
var people = [
     { name : "John",  age : 25 },
     { name : "Jane",  age : 49 },
     { name : "Jim",   age : 31 },
     { name : "Julie", age : 39 },
     { name : "Joe",   age : 19 },
     { name : "Jack",  age : 48 }
];
```

How can I loop through all the objects inside people and output their names along with their ages like so:

```
John 25
Jame 49
followed by the rest...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a for loop: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

```
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
{
     document.write(people[i].name + ' ' + people[i].age + '<br />'); 
}
```

or the `each` function in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$.each(people, function(i, o) {
   document.write(o.name + ' ' + o.age + '<br />'); 
});
```

Comment: yeah I figured that much, I need an example on what to do the loop on. people[0].length returns undefined.

Comment: `people` is already an array, just like in C. `people[0]` is the first element in your array, `people[0].length` would work if your `people[0]` is also an array.

Comment: that for loop will never loop, without `var i = 0;`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you want to write it to the page, but here's a sample with `document.write`:

```
for (var i = 0, ilen = people.length; i < ilen; i++)
{
   document.write(people[i].name + ' ' + people[i].age + '<br/>');
}
```

I highly recommend getting the length in the first expression of for-loop, not the second. In this case, `people.length` is not too expensive. But **if it is** costly and you put it in the second expression like so `for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++)`, then it'll get evaluated in **every loop** and you wonder where your CPU cycles went. :)

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you can do

```
$.each(people, function(){
  alert(this.name + " " + this.age);
});
```

If you want to just append it to a div you can do

```
$.map(people, function(){
  return this.name + " " + this.age + "<br/>";
}).appendTo("#myDiv");
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through them. These are Javascript object literals not JSON though, just FYI

```
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    alert(people[i].name + " " + people[i].age)
}
```

For example:

```
var variable = { 'key': 'value' };  // object
console.log(variable.key); // outputs: value

var json = '{"key":"value"}'; // javascript string representing valid json
console.log(json.key); // outputs: undefined

var jObj = JSON.parse(json); // now a javascript object from the json string
console.log(jObj.key); // outputs: value
```

So JSON only really exists in javascript as a representation.

Comment: hmm interesting, can you please give a quick explanation as to the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach):

```
people.forEach(function(person) {
    console.log(person.name, person.age)
});
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript1.6 feature, supported in Firefox1.5+ but NOT IE7 or below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jquery:

```
var people = [
     { name : "John",  age : 25 },
     { name : "Jane",  age : 49 },
     { name : "Jim",   age : 31 },
     { name : "Julie", age : 39 },
     { name : "Joe",   age : 19 },
     { name : "Jack",  age : 48 }
];

jQuery.each(people, function(index, person){
console.log([person.name, person.age].join(" ")) ;
});
```

Output:

```
John 25
Jane 49
Jim 31
Julie 39
Joe 19
Jack 48
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pQrV4/1/)**

Markup

```
<div id="people"></div>
```

JS

```
var people = [
     { name : "John",  age : 25 },
     { name : "Jane",  age : 49 },
     { name : "Jim",   age : 31 },
     { name : "Julie", age : 39 },
     { name : "Joe",   age : 19 },
     { name : "Jack",  age : 48 }
];

$(function(){
    var $people = $("#people");
    $.each(people, function(){
       $people.append("<div>").append("<span>"+this.name+"</span>"+this.age+"<br />");
    });
});
```

Css

```
#people
{
    width:70px;
    text-align:right;
}

#people span
{
    float:left;
}
```