# Basic Json/javascript query

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I'm a complete newbie to json. I'm trying to parse a json file into a web page just like explained in this thread.........

[Very basic JSON question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102092/very-basic-json-question)

However my json file is a large list of contacts that are not in an array like 'people' in the above example. instead the first 6 lines of my json file are like the following.

```
{ "first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Moore", "phone": "123456", "email": "tom@abc.ie" }
{ "first_name": "Fred", "last_name": "Power", "phone": "197412", "email": "fred@abc.ie" }
{ "first_name": "Ann", "last_name": "Doyle", "phone": "836547", "email": "ann@abc.ie" }
{ "first_name": "Phil", "last_name": "Jones", "phone": "927481", "email": "phil@abc.ie" }
{ "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Ross", "phone": "993377", "email": "jane@abc.ie" }
{ "first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Moore", "phone": "123456", "email": "tom@abc.ie" }
```

How can I loop through them to display like in the above thread? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can read the file, line by line, and add them to an array. This way will give you the 'people array' and you will able to loop through it effortless.

Comment: or for basic concepts, you can go for this useful and genuine link - 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLc7STlqyZm1rd7UI6xV0lNUvVXFmRjxSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is invalid. It needs square brackets around the outside, and commas between items. It should be:

```
[
    { "first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Moore", "phone": "123456", "email": "tom@abc.ie" },
    { "first_name": "Fred", "last_name": "Power", "phone": "197412", "email": "fred@abc.ie" },
    { "first_name": "Ann", "last_name": "Doyle", "phone": "836547", "email": "ann@abc.ie" },
    { "first_name": "Phil", "last_name": "Jones", "phone": "927481", "email": "phil@abc.ie" },
    { "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Ross", "phone": "993377", "email": "jane@abc.ie" },
    { "first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Moore", "phone": "123456", "email": "tom@abc.ie" }
]
```

`$.getJSON` handles the json parsing for you - just do:

```
$.getJSON('/url/of/the/json/file', function(people) {
    alert(people[0].first_name)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not json format then, so you won't be able to handle it with functions that are for json. I would suggest to use a lib/function on the server side to create correct json output, then it'll be much easier to use it in the client side as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = eval('[{ "first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Moore", "phone": "123456", "email": "tom@abc.ie" },{ "first_name": "Fred", "last_name": "Power", "phone": "197412", "email": "fred@abc.ie" },{ "first_name": "Ann", "last_name": "Doyle", "phone": "836547", "email": "ann@abc.ie" },{ "first_name": "Phil", "last_name": "Jones", "phone": "927481", "email": "phil@abc.ie" },{ "first_name": "Jane", "last_name": "Ross", "phone": "993377", "email": "jane@abc.ie" },{ "first_name": "Tom", "last_name": "Moore", "phone": "123456", "email": "tom@abc.ie" }]');

for (i in t) {
var data = t[i];
  for (k in data) {
    alert(k+" >> "+data[k])
  }
}
```

you can get "k" as key and  "data[k]" as value.

Comment: an object literal is not JSON.

Comment: then you can use eval function.

Comment: oh please god no - never - ever - use `eval` to parse JSON - use the built-in parser or a decent quality shim.

Comment: you can use any parser to parse json, this is just example.

Comment: in any event you haven't explained _why_ the OPs "json" was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned your JSON is not valid, if in doubt you can always check:

http://jsonlint.com/
or
http://json.parser.online.fr/